# How ignition coil in automobile works..?? what are the winding count for ignition coil..?

Tags: transformer, magnetics, coil, winding

I just want to make ignition coil on my own. can you please help to done primary and secondary winding for same..? 40KV output required from 12v input supply.

Comment: This might get better answers on [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There is a lot on the web about this. It is important to realise that Vout/Vin is NOT in proportion to the turns ratio. Energy is stored in the magnetic field in the core when Vin is applied. When The primary current is interrupted the collapsing field induces a much greater voltage in the secondary. SO you need to understand how the core characteristics affect the result. Turns ratio alone is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know not only the turns ratio, you also should know the wire diameter for primary and secondary winding. The core is important and a careful designed isolation. Using only the isolation of the wire would result in a ignition coil destroyed in a very short time by arcs inside the coil.
Read here and look at the pictures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignition_coil